# Отмена изменений в коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе используется простенький `UserControl` (модальное окно), в котором редактируется коллекция цветовых меток.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама коллекция выглядит следующим образом:

```
public static ObservableCollection<ColorVM> Colors { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ColorVM>()
{
    new ColorVM {Title = "Green", Value = "#a0db8e"},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Red", Value = "#b44545"},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Orange", Value = "#e28356"},
    new ColorVM {Title = "Blue", Value = "#2b90f5"}
};
```

Мне не понятно как реализовать метод кнопки `Cancel`, чтобы все изменения в коллекции откатывались на момент до начала редактирования. 
Была мысль реализовать `ICloneable` у `ColorVM` и копировать всю исходную коллекцию для редактирования в `UserControl`. Но я не уверен в правильности такого подхода.

Подскажите, как правильно такое реализуется?

Comment: Я за копирование полей из одного класса в другой. Каким образом - уже на ваше усмотрение. Можно интерфейс обязать реализовать, можно ручками, можно попытаться прикрутить генерируемый автоматически код копирования полей и свойств.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, клонирование — правильный подход.

Когда вы открываете ваш объект на редактирование, вы создаёте его клон. Есть два подхода:

1. либо вы даёте на редактирование клон, а при выборе юзером OK заменяете оригинал на клон,
2. либо вы даёте на редактирование оригинал, а при выборе Cancel заменяете отредактированный оригинал на клон.

При втором подходе остальные части программы видят изменения в редактируемом объекте прямо во время редактирования, так что этот подход сейчас, кажется, более модный.

---

Если коллекция *большая* (скажем, десятки или сотни тысяч элементов), имеет смысл подумать об оптимизации. Можно хранить не две копии коллекции, а одну, и набор *операций редактирования* в виде объектов, представляющих операции: добавление элемента, удаление, замена одного элемента на другой. Но этим не стоит заморачиваться пока производительность простого подхода остаётся нормальной.